# iPhone -- Layout manager for UIViews?

Tags: iphone, layout

I'm not sure whether "layout manager" is the correct term, but i'm looking for a way to get UIViews to flow into thier parent view, like left-floated div's would in an HTML page. Is there an easy way to do this, either via the iPhone api's or something external?

Comment: Was just thinking the same thing.  A collection of LayoutManagers like in Java Swing would be helpful when you really just don't want to bother with InterfaceBuilder but also don't want to have to deal with the complexities of positioning everything by hand.

Comment: There is just the webkit view if you only want to display stuff. I've been messing around with embedding html for nicely layed-out info screen stuff.

Comment: This doesn't really exist in iOS 5 or earlier. For information on iOS 6, consult your NDA-protected documentation which we can't discuss openly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of an API to do this. Core Animation on the Mac has some layout stuff but I think it was not included on the iPhone.

What you describe does not sound extremely difficult though. Open source it? :-)

Comment: Yes! I'm generally too sloppy/lazy/selfish for any of my open source intentions to go anywhere. But maybe this'll be different :)

Answer (score 2):

After doing some searching I found this: http://code.google.com/p/layoutmanagers/
Last Development was in Dec 2009 but at first glance, it seems like it can still be applicable to current versions of iOS.

Comment: I created a fork of the above on github: https://github.com/RefuX/LayoutManagers-Fork and added GridLayout. I've used it on iPhone and iPad UIs. For iOS 4 and 5. I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this really build into the sdk, but it shouldn't be too hard to get the behavior you're after. Just call

```
NSArray *subs = [parentView subviews];
```

to get all of the subviews already present. Loop through them like this

```
CGRect leftMostViewsFrame = nil;
for(UIView *cur in subs){
  CGRect where = cur.frame;
  //find the left most frame for a given X coord
}
```

and place your new view next to it

```
newView.frame = CGRectMake(leftMostViewsFrame.origin.x + leftMostViewsFrame.size.width, 
[parentView addSubview:newView];
```

......

You can write it much more cleanly than that and there is a lot more checking and reasoning you need to do to get all the behavior of float, but that is the basic approach i would take. I don't know if there is a third party lib you could use or not.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll go ahead and do that.

Comment: @morgancodes I wrote a complete solution based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11379438/974531

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete solution (based on [the answer by Joe Cannatti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203540/974531)):

1. **Add a [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)** to your storyboard, and link it to your [`ViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) under some name, e.g. `container`. (In case your container view is the whole view, you can use `self.view` instead of `container` within your `ViewController.m`.)
2. **Create and add UI elements** to `container`. For example, you can create and add a [`UILabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) to `container` with:

   ```
   UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   label.text = @"Foo";
   [label sizeToFit];
   [container addSubview:label];
   ```
3. Initially, and whenever you add/remove/modify UI elements to/from/within `container`, you can **re-arrange them into flow layout** with:

   ```
   float x = 0, y = 0, width = container.frame.size.width, rowHeight = 0;
   for (UIView* view in container.subviews) {
     // only re-arrange user-added views (change condition as required)
     if (![view isKindOfClass:UILabel.class]) continue;
     float w = view.frame.size.width, h = view.frame.size.height;
     bool fitsInRow = x + w <= width;
     if (!fitsInRow) {x = 0; y += rowHeight; rowHeight = h;}
     view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
     x += w;
     rowHeight = MAX(rowHeight, h);
   }
   // if container is a UIScrollView, change content size
   container.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, y + rowHeight);
   ```